# JRuby Rails brings up "invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII" on fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, utf-8, internationalization, jruby

I have an application that works perfectly in Rails 4.1.4 with Ruby 2.1.2.  When I switch to Rails 4.1.4 with JRuby 1.7.13 I get an encoding type error on the polymorphic relation addresses.  I'm using UTF-8 for internationalization.

This is the line it breaks on

```
<%= f.fields_for :addresses do |a| %>
```

My in-browser error is

```
ArgumentError at /contacts/new
invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
```

And the terminal says

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2139ms

ArgumentError - invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII:
  org/jruby/RubyRegexp.java:1642:in `==='
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb:117:in `blank?'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb:24:in `present?'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb:44:in `presence'
  actionview (4.1.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:39:in `capture'
  actionview (4.1.4) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1860:in `fields_for_nested_model'
  actionview (4.1.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
  actionview (4.1.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
  actionview (4.1.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
  actionview (4.1.4) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:699:in `fields_for'
  actionview (4.1.4) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1859:in `fields_for_nested_model'
  actionview (4.1.4) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1845:in `fields_for_with_nested_attributes'
  org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
  actionview (4.1.4) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1843:in `fields_for_with_nested_attributes'
  actionview (4.1.4) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1517:in `fields_for'
```

The snippet I see in `lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb:117` is

```
#
#   "\u00a0".blank? # => true
#
# @return [true, false]
def blank?
  BLANK_RE === self
end
```

I've declared UTF8 in many different places and configuration files, and they test out correctly.  This doesn't seem to be related to environment variables but rather the built-in code.

I've verified the form submits the utf8 parameter

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
```

### UTF8 Configurations

config/database.yml

```
default: &defaults
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: mydb
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *defaults
  adapter: postgresql
  database: dev_mydb
```

config/application.rb

```
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

config/boot.rb

```
ENV_JAVA['file.encoding'] = "UTF-8"
ENV['LC_ALL']   = "en_US.UTF-8"
ENV['LANG']     = "en_US.UTF-8"
ENV['LANGUAGE'] = "en_US.UTF-8"
```

Gemfile

```
if RUBY_VERSION =~ /1.9/ # assuming you're running Ruby ~1.9
  Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
  Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
end
```

As I said earlier the code works in Rails 4.1.4 with Ruby 2.1.2.  Help is appreciated.

Here's a snippet from my `db/schema.rb` file of the addresses table

```
# encoding: UTF-8
create_table "addresses", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "kind"
  t.string   "address1"
  t.string   "address2"
  t.string   "address3"
  t.string   "city"
  t.string   "state"
  t.string   "postal_code"
  t.string   "country"
  t.integer  "addressable_id"
  t.string   "addressable_type"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

There is a similar issue mentioned under JRuby issues on github https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/1562

Comment: I guess you already tried to add this at the beginning of your ContactsController

    # coding: utf-8

Comment: there have been bugs in JRuby around encoding before, over multiple versions of JRuby coming and going. It might be worth trying to isolate into a reproducible case to report to Jruby if it turns out to be a bug. Which is a huge pain, but I'm just saying in my experience a bug in JRuby is a possibility.  You might also want to check to make sure your `RUBY_VERSION =~ /1.9/` is getting triggered on jruby (could jruby be reporting a 2.x version instead?)